# How to realize inheritance in Typo3 6.2 Extension?

Tags: typo3, backend, extend, typo3-6.2.x

My goal is being able to:

1. Create `Expertise` Entries in the backend (already accomplished)
2. Create `SubExpertise` Entries in the backend

   - **(same props as `Expertise` but
     they belong to one or many `Expertise`)**
3. Create `AdditionalInfoTitles` Entries in the backend

   - (they can belong to one or many `Expertise` OR `SubExpertise`)
   - **I want to be able to choose Objects from all `Expertise` AND `SubExpertise` when creating a new entry**

Right now I can only choose between all `Expertise`-Entries:
[image]

That's why I thought about inheritance since then `SubExpertise` would be of the same type as `Expertise` and therefore automatically displayed in the `Expertise` list in a `AdditionalInfoTitles` entry. But that's just my theory and I'm kinda stuck in reality with typo3 TCA and other knowledge that I'm lacking...

In my extension builder I made following (don't mind the *subExpertises* property)[image]
Then I added `expertise` to the `Overrides` folder, because I'm trying to extend it with `subexpertise`:

```
<?php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
        die ('Access denied.');
}

$temporaryColumns = array (
        'expertise' => array(
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:appoints/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_appoints_domain_model_subexpertise.expertise',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_appoints_domain_model_subexpertise',
            'MM' => 'tx_appoints_subexpertise_expertise_mm',
            'size' => 10,
            'autoSizeMax' => 30,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'wizards' => array(
                '_PADDING' => 1,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                'edit' => array(
                    'module' => array(
                        'name' => 'wizard_edit',
                    ),
                    'type' => 'popup',
                    'title' => 'Edit',
                    'icon' => 'edit2.gif',
                    'popup_onlyOpenIfSelected' => 1,
                    'JSopenParams' => 'height=350,width=580,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
                    ),
                'add' => Array(
                    'module' => array(
                        'name' => 'wizard_add',
                    ),
                    'type' => 'script',
                    'title' => 'Create new',
                    'icon' => 'add.gif',
                    'params' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_appoints_domain_model_expertise',
                        'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                        'setValue' => 'prepend'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns(
        'tx_appoints_domain_model_expertise',
        $temporaryColumns
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
        'tx_appoints_domain_model_expertise',
        'expertise'
);
```

But I don't think I'm going into the right direction with this - 
Because I think this way I'm not gonna be able to add a `SubExpertise` in the backend separately from an `Expertise` - I already have the same problem with my Objects that extend `fe_user` because when creating them I usually have to go through a new User and then set the extension type - but this way I don't have separate listings of the different entities that extend `fe_user`.

Comment: Is there any other difference between `Expertise` and `SubExpertise` than the fact the latter has one or more parents? If not I'd treat them as one and the same and just create `Expertise` objects. Same question for `AdditionalInfoTitle`s.

Comment: Yes, Expertise and SubExpertise are the same with the difference that SubExpertise can belong to one or more Expertise.
AdditionalInfoTitle is completely different and it's properties are not relevant for this question - except its Expertise-Property for which I want to be able to choose Expertise and SubExpertise entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get rid of the separation between Expertise and SubExpertise for the most part. According to your description a SubExpertise cannot have another SubExpertise as its parent, so you can adapt the select field that it only lists Expertises which have an empty parent field.
By removing the difference the problem of selecting (Sub)Expertise's in AdditionalInfoTitles is removed; it's just one and the same type of objects.

If you need to differentiate in the presentation in the BE forms there are plenty of options to adjust the labels of the listed items, use a function of your own to build the list or even a custom form element.

In Extbase you can simply write a few functions in your repository to fetch Expertise's, SubExpertise's or both.

Comment: thanks - today I also started thinking about if having one entity wouldn't make things simpler - I will try it out and once it works I will mark your answer as accepted! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the entity `SubExpertise` does not have a meaning in your domain model, Jigal's answer is perfect for your scenario. If it does have a meaning, you can achieve that using single table inheritance in Extbase.

```
class Expertise extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
    // all common properties
}

class SubExpertise extends Expertise
{
    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\[YourVendorName]\Appoints\Domain\Model\Expertise>
     */
    protected $expertises;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->expertises = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    }

    public function getExpertises() {}
    public function setExpertises($expertises) {}
}
```

Via TypoScript then you have to define mapping rules, since both `Expertise` and `SubExpertise` would be stored in the same table `tx_appoints_domain_model_subexpertise`.

You'll find more details on single table inheritance in the [Extbase book](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/5-modeling-the-class-hierarchy.html).

Comment: thank you too for an alternative - when I will finally have some time I will read deeper through both approaches and depending on which one is better for me to execute I will choose the accepted answer :)